# jQuery ui draggable table by single row

Tags: jquery, user-interface, html-table, draggable

I have a draggable table which all working fine, though I want to be able to drag it  from the `<th>` row inside the table, not from all the `<td>`'s.

```
<table id="draggable">
<tr>
<th id="drag">header (can drag table from here)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>normal column (can't drag the table from here)</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ opacity: 0.5 });
</script>
```

How can I deal this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiya **working Demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/rAzL8/ **&** http://jsfiddle.net/rAzL8/1/

Cooleos, so all you need to use `:handle` property on `th` tag on your table with draggable and bingo it will just handle the th tag of your table. hope this helps, CHeers

**Jquery Code**

```
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ opacity: 0.7, handle:'#drag' });

 ​
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="draggable">
<tr>
<th id="drag">header (can drag table from here)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>normal column (can't drag the table from here) ;)</td> <td>another</td>
</tr>

    <tr>
<td>normal column (can't drag the table from here) ;) </td>
</tr>

    <tr>
<td>normal column (can't drag the table from here);) </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: One slight question, how can I set the max draggable distance, so it cannot be dragged outside the page ?

Comment: Hiya, sure: you mean this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-distance , have a nice one!